# Different starting number for each user type

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a database for a website that will have multiple users type.

- Admin
- Student
- Teacher

I want The user ID for each type to start with a specific number then auto-increment when new user register

For example

- The First admin ID should be 01
- The 10th student ID 110
- The 100th teacher 2100

How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Don't give too much meaning to an id: it is just to identify a row, nothing more

Comment: Instead of that, use a column called for exmple `type` and place the 0 or 1 or 2 in there. If you must have this as part ot the users _Code?_ then concatenate the `id` and the `type` together BUT ONLY IN THE PRESENTATION Layer

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select
    u.*,
    row_number() over(partition by user_type order by id) + case user_type
        when 'Admin'   then 0
        when 'Student' then 99
        when 'Teacher' then 1999
    end as new_id
from users
```

This assumes that column `id` is the primary key of the table. I would not recommend storing this information, which can be dynamically computed as shown above. If you are going to use this on a regular basis, you can create a view.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably store students, admins, and teachers in different tables.  Presumably, they are different entities in your data model -- for instance, "students" *attend* classes but "teachers" *teach* them.

Then if you really want you can set the auto_increment value to a different starting value in each table.

If you are just registering users for online access and your data model has nothing to do with the operations of a school, then just use an auto-incremented id.  I strongly do not recommend encoding additional information in the id.  It is available in the type column of the table.

If you *really* want ids that represent the different groups, you can add a computed column.  I would recommend using strings for this:

```
alter table users add typed_user_id as
    (concat(left(user_type, 1), lpad(user_id, 4, '0'))
```